Is an attic window replacement subject to egress code requirements?
I replaced a window in the attic because the inspector said there should be an egress window there. When I replaced it, I was told it wasn't up to code because it didn't meet egress by two inches. I don't believe the window she had me replace was big enough to meet egress code without altering the hole to make it larger first. Now she wants me to take out the egress window and install  another new egress window. I don't want to replace it again. Isn't this supposed to be grandfathered in?

Depends on why it is being inspected in the first place. If you remodeled you attic to make it living space, then, yes, code would say you need egress now.

A window that doesn't meet egress standards isn't an "egress window". You shouldn't refer to them as such. Please revise to fix that and explain your overall project scope better.

why did the inspector show up in the first place?


Isn't this supposed to be grandfathered in?

This ship sailed, don't worry about it. IIRC there is no word "grandfathered" in The Code
At least in my jurisdiction, two things are correct about inspectors:

They don't care about your problems, money you spent, or what you are trying to do; they come to enforce The Code and most of the times you can't argue with The Code
However, they can be friendly and willing to explain what exactly you are doing wrong/right if you ask them nicely; sometimes they are not very nice with contractors, but willing to help out a homeowner

So you need to have a dialogue with the inspector (or their supervisor) about what exactly you need to do. Make drawings if necessary so that you are both on the same page

The key question, as I understand is intended use.
A bedroom has very strict rules, for a very good reason: if someone wakes up to smoke or fire in the middle of the night, they need to be able to get out quickly and easily without going through other rooms.
At the other extreme is storage, where there is, as far as I know, no need for egress at all other than the main entrance to the room. If your plans for remodeling the attic look like it could be a bedroom then an inspector is likely to be strict.
In between would be a room that is not normally a bedroom but might be used sometimes as a guest bedroom. That is where it gets really subjective. I learned years ago from a real estate agent that because of egress requirements many basement "bedrooms" can't be included in the count of bedrooms in a house for sale. But when a room is being renovated the usage may change, so an inspector could see that you are:

Adding a carpeted floor
Adding built in lighting fixtures
Adding HVAC or extending the existing HVAC to include the attic
Adding a full bathroom

and decide you are really putting a new master bedroom suite and not a home office.
In my example, changing a full bathroom (with tub or shower) to a half bathroom might help - after all who needs a full bathroom next to a home office? Another thing you could do in this example is to include built-in shelving and counters all around that are clearly for an office rather than a bedroom. Of course, those changes may not be relevant to your situation. But basically it comes down to convincing the inspector that the room is not an egress-required room. You may simply not be able to do that.
Unlike many other code items - e.g., updated electrical requirements - egress is a really critical thing where it is not just about preventing a problem but about dealing with occasional extremely serious problems. In my neighborhood around 20 years or so ago there were a series of very serious home fires - one electrical, one lighting that caught bedding on fire, one due to a candle. In at least two of them, easy egress was absolutely critical.

It is very unfair, but you have to do what the inspector says.
In the US we have created this insane system, in which we have deputized building commissioners with the power to make you spend thousands of dollars in unnecessary repairs depending on how they feel that day.
In your case, see if you can speak with a contractor in the know. They might be able to tell you the exact keywords you need to say in order to make the window OK. For example, in my town, you have to always call things "repair" and you can get away with anything -- it's code-speak for what you are calling granfathered. And there's no limit about how much you are "repair" before it's effective replacement (see the paradox of the Ship of Theseus.). If you write "replace" in the permit application, a whole new rulebook applies. Sometimes it's not what you are doing, but the cost. For example, there are rules that say that if you improve the house by more than than $X,  the whole house has to be brought up to code, which for an old house (the majority around here), would be nothing short of reconstruction of the house. But you can do $X/2 improvements split into two permits, one after the other, and nothing is triggered. Then there's another rule for percentage of the value of the house, another rule for increases or conversions of the living area, etc.
Another problem you have is that means of egress has to do with fire safety and is one of the few areas of the code most inspectors are very strict about. Still, it varies a lot. I recently finished remodeling a house, and during inspection the guy took out a ruler and measured that the steps in the main stair were within 1/8" of the allowed measurements. But one room had a single, 12x12" inoperable window, and he just shrugged it off as "well, that's an old house for you."

only parts of this answer the question specifically
